# Two auxiliary routes manipulating each other's routing

Tags: angular, angular-routing

So, my app scheme looks like this. There is a primary outlet divided into two auxiliary outlets- **Sidenav outlet** and **Content outlet** which load **two different modules**.

[image]

My issue is, I can't figure out how to change routing (Using routerLinks) of **Sidenav outlet** using **Content outlet** and vice versa. Also, I would like to manipulate two routes at once, which does not seem to work as well with what I tried so far.

I've tried using this

`<a [routerLink]="['/home', { outlets: { 'sidenav': ['/some/route'], 'content': ['/some/other_route'] } } ]">Navigate</a>`

But it does not work, I get the error as routes would not exist (Though I can set them just by editing the path at the top of the browser).

My wild guess is that [routerLink] placed inside of Content Outlet searches for child outlet named sidenav, instead of its peers. But I have no idea how to make a workaround.

EDIT: My routing file looks something like this

`const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'core',
    component: CoreComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'some',
        outlet: 'sidenav',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('...').then(
            (m) => m.Module
          )
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'some',
        outlet: 'sidenav',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'some_different',
        outlet: 'content',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('...').then(
            (m) => m.Module
          )
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'some_different',
        outlet: 'content',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'core',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];`

In each child module there are just ordinary routes with nothing special.

Comment: can you show your routing file?

Comment: @JadavPalak just edited

Answer (score 0):

You could use the "data" object in your angular routes "root or childs" to read some specific Information. Maybe this will help you out.

Comment: I'm not sure how could I use data object in above case